# "Great Dying" reduction in biomass

Tags: paleontology, mass-extinction

In "The Great Dying" [About 250 million years ago, at the end of the Permian period, something killed some 90 percent of the planet's species. Less than 5 percent of the animal species in the seas survived. On land less than a third of the large animal species made it.](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/prehistoric-world/permian-extinction/)

I presume the surviving species were reduced in number. Is there any information on by how much, or how much the total biomass was reduced?

Comment: I don't think there is such a study. The kings of biomass are bacteria and algae and the event hapenned long time ago.

Comment: @Universal_learner I was thinking in terms of the fossil record, but there could be ["biosignatures"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biosignature) of microbial life.

Comment: not much you are switching from megafauna to bacteria.